# What is an upper bound to a number of positive solutions to $n = x^d + y^d + z^d $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Let $d$ be a positive integer greater than $2$ and let $n$ be some natural number. I was wondering if someone could tell me what is an upper bound to a number of solutions $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{N}^3$ to $n = x^d + y^d + z^d $? I would also appreciate any references! Thank you very much!

Comment: A mildly trivial bound is $n^{3/d}$, achieved by noting that $x^d\leq n$, so $x\leq n^{1/d}$, so there are at most $n^{1/d}$ possible values of $x$, and similarly for $y,z$. I'm sure there are better bounds known though.

Comment: Once $x$ and $y$ is chosen, then $z$ is fixed. a trivial improvement of @Wojowu 's bound is $n^{2/d}$.

Comment: Try the circle method,